# Hook Keys by Raw Input instead of Low Level Hook

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-hook

A my old utility (a little hotkey utility for poker online), based on the low level hook SetWindowsHookEx API, works perfectly with Win7, but the keyboard hook crashes frequently with Win 10.

In Msdn I read:

> The hook procedure should process a message in less time than the data
> entry specified in the LowLevelHooksTimeout value in the following
> registry key:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
>
> The value is in milliseconds. If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the
> message to the next hook. **However, on Windows 7 and later, the hook is**
> **silently removed without being called**. There is no way for the
> application to know whether the hook is removed.
> Note  Debug hooks cannot track this type of low level keyboard hooks.
> If the application must use low level hooks, **it should run the hooks**
> **on a dedicated thread** that passes the work off to a worker thread and
> then immediately returns

I do so, using a BackGroundWorker (with hook times of 1-2 milliseconds!!) but in any case in Win 10 Hooks stop to work randomly and frequently.

I can also read:

> In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, **it
> should monitor raw input instead**. This is because raw input can
> asynchronously monitor mouse and keyboard messages that are targeted
> for other threads more effectively than low level hooks can. For more
> information on raw input, see Raw Input.

Ok, but there is a problem: using Raw Input I can get the pressed keys, **but how to freeze the pressed keys**?? With a low level hooh I can write: **e.Handled = True** in the KeyDown event, but using Raw Input I can't see nothing of similar.

Comment: If your hook stops working it's more likely that there's something wrong with your implementation. Please try my implementation in my [InputHelper library](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper) (compiled download [here](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases)) and see how it works. You can find implementation details on the Wiki: [Low-Level keyboard hook](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/wiki/Low-level-keyboard-hook).

Comment: In InputHelper `e.Block = True` should be the same as `e.Handled = True`.

Comment: @Visual Vincent -Lol, just for try... one hour to debug dozens of errors importing your code... compiled and imported the dll in the project... it works fine, but the hook stops to work EXACTLY like my previous code: randomly after pressing several times the keys. IN FACT this is a NOTE problem of Windows 10, that does not like low level hooks.

Comment: The DLL comes precompiled as I mentioned in my comment, you shouldn't have had to go through all that work. It's weird though, because I have been using it for a while now as well as a couple of other people here on SO and so far none of us have experienced the issue that you have. What is the value of the `LowLevelHooksTimeout` entry in your registry?

Comment: Also, which exact version of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: Sobstituted my compiled dll with YOUR compiled one: nothing changes.
The LowLevelHooksTimeout item IS NOT present in my registry, but I read that the default value is 200 ms, while my hook time (since I move the working code to another thread) is under 10 ms, usually 2 ms!!.
Windows 10 Pro version 1809.
I REPEAT: IT'S NOT A HOOK PROBLEM, IS A WIN 10 PROBLEM THAT DON'T LIKES CONTINUAL  HOOKING. And a hotkey utility working on 6 poker tables open at the same time works even 3-6 times in 10 seconds.

Comment: Yes I know you said it's Windows 10, that's why I asked which version you were running. Substituting the DLLs wouldn't have made a difference, my reply was just a hint that you wouldn't have had to struggle with the code for an hour nor compile it yourself.

Comment: From what I have and haven't found (and you as well it seems, based on [a post on MSDN in 2016](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2c94a2f3-4d38-45e8-9554-a689c8ccae4a/how-to-quotfreezequot-block-a-key-using-raw-input?forum=vbgeneral)), it appears one cannot block keystrokes merely via raw input. Hooks are unfortunately the easiest way to go. -- Also I'm curious as to what exactly you mean by _continual hooking_? Do you create multiple hooks in the same app? It would help if you could include a shorter snippet showing how you use your hooks.

Comment: Continual Hooking: 6 open tables of poker online. Pressing the Key "A" (for example) user FOLDS on the table in the foreground. Obviously he don't want to write "A" in the chat, so the key MUST be freezed (e.Handle = True). And since the FOLD action is the most recurrent, he can press "A" even one time per second to Fold in all the tables, if the  poker session is a very quick Zoom one. That is exactly what Win 10 silently removes without being called.

Comment: Okay, so what you are saying is that your app is repeating that action a certain number of times (or every time) when the user presses the 'A' key? -- Also I don't think "Continual Hooking" is the right term to use as it implies that you are continuously adding or re-adding hooks. Now, if possible I'd like to see a small example of your hook code so that I can attempt to reproduce the problem on my end (you can recreate the basics in a small project from scratch if you like, just as long as it still reproduces the issue for you).

Comment: I've now tested the hooks on Windows 7, Windows 10 1803 and Windows 10 1809 and I cannot seem to reproduce the issue. It would appear that the trouble is with your PC and not Windows itself (but without seeing your code I cannot tell for sure). Try installing the latest updates and/or repairing your Windows installation and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: The hook doesn't even get removed when the execution time exceeds `LowLevelHooksTimeout`. It just passes the keystroke along the rest of the hook chain and eventually reaches the target application. When pressing a key again the hook still responds. I suggest you test this on another PC to see if you still experience the same issue. If you do, the problem is most likely caused by your code or by a faulty Windows installation, and not the actual OS itself.